# Finding covering spaces of $\mathbb RP^2\vee \mathbb RP^2$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

My question is connected (pun intended) to the Exercise 1.3.14 of Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

The question is to find all connected covering spaces of $\mathbb RP^2\vee \mathbb RP^2.$ I understand how to solve the problem by first finding the fundamental group of $\mathbb RP^2\vee \mathbb RP^2$ and then computing the covers corresponding to the subgroups of the fundamental group. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472796/find-all-connected-covering-space-of-mathbb-rp2-vee-mathbb-rp2) provides a detailed solution as of how to find the connected covering spaces.

My question is this: how do we find the covering spaces of $\mathbb RP^2\vee \mathbb RP^2.$ that are not connected? Are there any general techniques or methods that can be used to answer this question?

Thank you!

Comment: if you dont add the path conected requisite, i belive the covers are just disjoint union of path conected covers.

Comment: @Fran Aguayo
 Could you please elaborate? What did you mean by "if you don't add path connected requisite"?

Comment: i am not sure all covers will be like that, but there will be a family of not conected covers that will be the disjoint union of conected covers, with the map define by parts in each of them.  like for a example, for a space X the union of any number of disjoint X, will be a cover to X, with the map "identity". and in just that case you have infinitly many covers, and this can be done for any cover $p:Y \to X$ (the disjoint union of any number of Y will cover X, with the map p*, p*(y) = p(y).

Comment: so that is why i think when they say find all covers, they mean conected ones (i made the mistake of saying path connected insted of conected in the first comment)

Comment: @Fran Aguayo
 Ohh that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Our space $X$ is locally path-connected, so any covering space of it will be locally path-connected, hence topologically the disjoint union of its components and each of those components is necessarily a connected covering space. So what @FranAguaygo describes are indeed all covers.